# SOAPpy returning an XML string. How do I get the library to parse the xml for me?

Tags: python, soap, soappy

I am using SOAPpy, and Dive Into Python http://diveintopython3.ep.io/http-web-services.html says it should be returning a dictionary.
I am making a simple request, that returns an xml response that has the escape characters.

```
WSDLFILE = 'path/to/my/wsdl'
_server = WSDL.Proxy(WSDLFILE)
print _server.validServerMethod(client,password)
```

This returns a big ugly str of xml 
`&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;it....`

Can anyone help me with getting this to return an already parsed response? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to unescape it : http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml